# Ubuntu 78 degree on Normal Work

Tags: 18.04, temperature

I have a Laptop

```
Version: F.19
Version: Type1ProductConfigId
Version: 70.30
Version: Chassis Version
Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
SBDS Version: 1
String: Compiler Version: VC 9.0
```

Plus 256gb ssd and 2gb Nvdia MX110

I am doing normal coding in VS code using Python and some other tasks such as ppt application is opened.

I checked my laptop temperature and it was in 70s using `sensors` command. Is it good/normal temperature? Laptop is pretty new and working fine

[image: Laptop Temprature image]

Comment: If working with a few programs running and only going up to 70s for a bit, not bad.  If it is always reading 70 plus even at idle, something to look into.

Comment: At 52C, that's fine, esp at idle. Temporary movement to 70C during heavy processing are fine too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Normally it is 52 when I am doing normal tasks.